# nginx + gunicorn + django not working

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I am taking the help of following docs http://tutos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/ndg.html and trying to run the server. I have following file in sites-enabled :

```
upstream test_server {
  server unix:/var/www/test/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=10s;
}

# This is not neccessary - it's just commonly used
# it just redirects example.com -> www.example.com
# so it isn't treated as two separate websites
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name dehatiengineers.in;
        return 301 $scheme://www.dehatiengineers.in$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen   80;
    server_name www.dehatiengineer.in;

    client_max_body_size 4G;

    access_log /var/www/test/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /var/www/test/logs/nginx-error.log warn;

    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias   /var/www/test/ourcase/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias   /var/www/test/ourcase/media/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://test_server;
            break;
        }
    }

    #For favicon
    location  /favicon.ico {
        alias /var/www/test/test/static/img/favicon.ico;
    }
    #For robots.txt
    location  /robots.txt {
        alias /var/www/test/test/static/robots.txt ;
    }
    # Error pages
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
        root /var/www/test/ourcase/static/;
    }
}
```

My server's domain name is `dehatiengineers.in`.

The `gunicorn_start.sh` file is:

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="ourcase"                              #Name of the application (*)
DJANGODIR=/var/www/test/ourcase             # Django project directory (*)
SOCKFILE=/var/www/test/run/gunicorn.sock        # we will communicate using this unix socket (*)
USER=root                           # the user to run as (*)
GROUP=webdata                                     # the group to run as (*)
NUM_WORKERS=1                                     # how many worker processes should Gunicorn spawn (*)
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=ourcase.settings             # which settings file should Django use (*)
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=ourcase.wsgi                     # WSGI module name (*)

echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"

# Activate the virtual environment
cd $DJANGODIR
source /var/www/test/venv/bin/activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

# Create the run directory if it doesn't exist
RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

# Start your Django Unicorn
# Programs meant to be run under supervisor should not daemonize themselves (do not use --daemon)
exec /var/www/test/venv/bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --user $USER \
  --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE
```

Now, I am running both of my nginx and `gunicorn_start.sh` file. nginx is running, as you can see at `http://www.dehatiengineers.in/` but the django is not connected to nginx. Now on `sudo sh  gunicorn_start.sh`, I am getting following output:

```
Starting ourcase as root
gunicorn_start.sh: 16: gunicorn_start.sh: source: not found
[2016-05-20 06:21:45 +0000] [10730] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.5.0
[2016-05-20 06:21:45 +0000] [10730] [INFO] Listening at: unix:/var/www/test/run/gunicorn.sock (10730)
[2016-05-20 06:21:45 +0000] [10730] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2016-05-20 06:21:45 +0000] [10735] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10735
```

But, in browser, I am just getting nginx output, not the original one.

Apart from this, I am having issue in running `gunicorn_ourcase.service` file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Ourcase gunicorn daemon

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
ExecStart=/var/www/test/gunicorn_start.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

running issues:

```
$ systemctl enable gunicorn_ourcase
systemctl: command not found
```

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Which linux distribution version do you use?

Comment: `Linux ip-172-31-26-242 3.13.0-74-generic #118-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 17 22:52:10 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Ubuntu version 14.04 or lower does not support systemd (systetmctl). There is Upstart instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything I was doing was fine, except the fact that `nginx` was using it's default config file. I had to delete/edit the file located in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` , with name `default`. After editing it, everything works fine.